# The meaning of " rested the length of"

Tags: meaning

> At the end of bohereen was a green gate; not green with paint, it had
>   ever been painted, but from age; and it sagged from its hinges and
>   **rested the length of its lower bar** on the floor of bohereen. This was a hunt that very seldom used gates, for they took too long to open.

This is from "The Story of Mona Sheehy" by Lord Dunsany.

I don't understand the meaning of the sentence. below.
I'd like to know how the gate sagged.
I am glad if somebody would kindly teach me.

> 

Answer (score 1):

"Sag" has its dictionary meaning "sink, subside, or bulge downwards under weight"

In this case the gate is not bulging, but it is not horizontal.  The part of the gate that opens is sloping down, so the bottom of the gate (the lower bar) is touching the ground. It would have been hard to open because the bottom of the gate is dragging on the ground.  Typically, gates are made of five horizontal bars of wood, with vertical and diagonal support struts.

If the gate was not sagging, it would not touch the ground.

"Bohereen" is a borrowing from Irish Gaelic (bóithrín) meaning little road (this word is not used outside of Ireland)

Comment: James K, thank you so much for you detailed answer. It is so helpful for me!